# Jackson: Json having json array to java class having list of another Java class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using jackson  2.6.x 
I am unable to convert the json to java class

```
public class ParentTest {
@JsonProperty("ParentTest")
public List<Test> getTestList() {
    return testList;
}

public void setTestList(List<Test> testList) {
    this.testList = testList;
}

@JsonProperty("ParentTest")
List<Test> testList;

public ParentTest(List<Test> testList)
{   
    this.testList = testList;
}

public ParentTest()
{
    super();
    testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
}

public String toString()
{
    String r = "";
    if(testList!=null)
    for(Test t : testList)
    {
        r += "Test:"+t.field1+t.field2; 
    }
    else
        r = "null";
    return r;
}}
```

And the class used for list is

```
@JsonRootName("Test")public class Test {
@JsonProperty("field1")
String field1;
@JsonProperty("field2")
String field2;
public Test(String field1,String field2)
{

    this.field1 = field1;

    this.field2 = field2;
}
public String getField1() {
    return field1;
}
public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public String getField2() {
    return field2;
}
public void setField2(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}}
```

And My Json is

```
{"ParentTest":   [{
"Test":{
        "field1":"t1",
        "field2":"t2"
         }
},
{
"Test":{
        "field1":"t3",
        "field2":"t4"
         }
}]}
```

And to read it I have used

```
public final class HandlerJacksonUtils {
private static ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
private static JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();

    public static <T> Object fromJson(String jsonAsString, Class<T> pojoClass) throws IOException {
        m.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return m.readValue(jsonAsString, pojoClass);
    }}
```

and then

```
ParentTest pt = (ParentTest) HandlerJacksonUtils.fromJson(json, ParentTest.class);
```

The ParentTest object pt prints nothing on System.out.print(pt.toString);

Comment: Have you tried specifing a constructor for your ParentTest class with the @JSonCreator anotation?

Comment: Your test case fails for me with an unsuitable constructor for `Test` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JsonRootName` does not work alone, as stated in javadocs.
You should use it in combination with `SerializationFeature#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` and/or `DeserializationFeature#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`.
But it works only for root object that you want to serialize/deserialize. So, it won't work in your case.
Instead, you can make a wrapper class for `Test`

```
public class TestWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("Test")
    private Test test;

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

And use it instead of `Test` in `ParentTest`